# Webview elements inspection for testing

Tags: ui-automation, appium, android-testing, android-uiautomator

We have a web view in our app which is being detected as a single webpage element (android.webkit.WebView). not showing the layout hierarchy to inspect individual UI components. I have tried to inspect the elements using 'UI Automator Viewer' and 'Appium Inspector' and same results. Is there any other tool which can be used for inspecting web views? Please advise!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIAutomatorViewer is able to see native elements only. Everything underneath WebView is web elements. You need to switch from native to web context.
[Link](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/advanced-concepts/hybrid.md)

Comment: @Kirill...how do I switch the view to view web context components?  Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyWu you can use Chrome devtools. See this guide https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was broken in Android Lollipop but appears to have recently been fixed with Android System Webview v44, try upgrading webview and inspecting then